# How can I combine these calls to print()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

In my program I need to output a list of points in a grid (tuples of row and column). However, sometimes rows and columns need to be swapped. Currently, I do it like this:

```
 if swapped:
    for col, row in points:
        print(row, col)
 else:
    for row, col in points:
        print(row, col)
```

Is there any way I can do it with a single call to `print()`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, swap them:

```
for col, row in points:
    if swapped:
        col, row = row, col
    print(col, row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean?

```
for col, row in points:
    print(row + ' ' + col if swapped else col + ' ' + row)
```

Output would be as expected with just using one `print`.

Comment: This is the most concise version, I guess. I was hoping I could use a pair of generators to avoid checking `swapped` on each iteration though

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most simple way to do a swap in python is the following:

```
s1, s2 = s2, s1
```

In your care the code could look like this

```
for col, row in points:
  if swapped:
    col, row = row, col
  print(row, col)
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look on below solution, swap the variable:

```
for col, row in points:
    if swapped:
        row, col = col, row
    print(row, col)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well

```
points = [(1,2), (3,4)]
swapped = True
for col, row in points:
    print((row, col) if swapped else (col, row))
#(2, 1)
#(4, 3)
```

Another example is

```
points = [(1,2.5), ('x',4)]
swapped = False
for col, row in points:
    print((row, col) if swapped else (col, row))
#(1, 2.5)
#('x', 4)
```